# Cohomology groups inherit Grading from Complex

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded ring with unique maximal ideal $R_{+}$ generated by all elements positive degree in $(\mathbb{N}_{>0})^n$ and we consider a bounded complex of $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded $R$-modules $M_i$ having only in degrees $0,.., n$ non zero entries:

$$   0  \xrightarrow{\partial_{0}} M_0 \xrightarrow{\partial_1} M_1     \xrightarrow{\partial_2} M_2 ... \xrightarrow{\partial_n} M_n \xrightarrow{} 0 $$

where we assume that the coboundary maps $\partial_i$ respect the grading: $\partial_i(M_{i-1, \alpha}) \subset M_{i, \alpha}$ for every grade $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Next we do the most usual thing at this stage by taking cohomology $H^i(M):= \text{ker }\partial_{i+1}/ \text{im }\partial_{i}$ with respect this complex and I'm posting the question why the cohomology groups $H^i(M)$ should inherit also a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-grading?

It is known that if $N \subset M$ is a $R$-submodule of a graded module $M$, which is generated by homogeneous elements of $M$, then $N$ inherits grading from $M$ via $N_{\alpha}:= N \cap M_{\alpha}$. Then the quotient $M/N$ inherits also a grading via $(M/N)_{\alpha} := M_{\alpha}/N_{\alpha} $. The problem here is that I not see any plausible reason why $\text{ker }\partial_{i} $ and $\text{im }\partial_{j} $ should inherit $\mathbb{Z}^n$-gradings from $M_i$, since there is no reason why these $R$-submodules are generated by homogeneous elements of the $M_i$.

But nevertheless in R. Stanley's  [Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b139094)in the section treating local cohomology on page 37 it is stated that the cohomology groups $H^i(M)$ should still inherit the $\mathbb{Z}^n$-grading from the objects of the complex. Why is this true?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if the boundary maps are graded then shouldn't the kernal and image also be graded?

Comment: ups thanks, after taking a second look that's rather obvious. indeed, for kernel of homogeneous map $\phi: A \to B$ I claim that $\text{ker } \phi= \oplus_i \text{ker } \phi_i$ where $\phi_i: A_i \to B_i \subset B$ are the restrictions to homogeneous parts. Let $a \in \text{ker } \phi$, then $a= \sum_i a_i$ decomposed in homogeneous parts as element of $A$. But then  $0= \phi(a)= \sum_i \phi(a_i)$ implies that $ \phi(a_i)=0$ as $\phi$ preserves the grading. for the image the argument is similar